# Choose which attributes to serialize

Tags: javascript, css, dom, serialization, xml-serialization

**When serializing a `div` into string with `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString()`, I would like to choose which DOM attributes to serialize.**

Example :

```js
var blah = document.getElementById('blah');
var blah1 = document.getElementById('blah1');
blah1.style.top = "100px";
console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(blah));
```

```css
#blah1 { position: absolute; }
```

```html
<div id="blah"><div id="blah1">Bonjour1</div></div>
```

For example, instead of ...

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="blah"><div id="blah1" style="top: 100px;">Bonjour1</div></div>
```

... I would like to serialize everything except the `top` style attribute :

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="blah"><div id="blah1">Bonjour1</div></div>
```

**How to choose which attributes to serialize when using `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString()`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. deep clone the tree with `node.cloneNode(true)` and insert into a DocumentFragment
2. use `fragment.querySelectorAll("[style]")` to find all elements that have the attribute you wish to remove
3. remove attributes from matched elements
4. serialize fragment

---

```
var blah = document.getElementById('blah');
var blah1 = document.getElementById('blah1');

blah1.style.top = "100px";

var frag = new DocumentFragment()
frag.appendChild(blah.cloneNode(true))

for(var e of frag.querySelectorAll("[style]")) {
   e.removeAttribute("style")
}

console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(frag))
```

Tested with Firefox 33

Comment: I tried similar things unsuccessfuly, but I think I was not using `DocumentFragment`. Would you have a short code example? I'll be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: Sure, no problem. But all I did was adding 4 LoCs to your example

Comment: Thanks @the8472! One last thing: how to do it if I only want to delete the `style="top: ..."`  part but, for example, keep a `style="transform: ...` part?  If I want this, I cannot simply do `e.removeAttribute("style")`, right?

Comment: then you just unset the style you've set previously

Comment: how to unset? with `e.style.top = "";` ?  or with something else ?

Comment: that's basic javascript/DOM manipulation. If you don't know how to I suggest reading some documentation/tutorials/whatever.